# URL Match patterns in firefox addons

Tags: firefox-addon, pattern-matching, firefox-addon-sdk

I am unable to figure out how can I use regular expression match patterns in Firefox addons (using Add-on Builder). I tried using [`match-pattern` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/docs/match-pattern.html).

My `main.js` looks like this:

```js
var { MatchPattern } = require("match-pattern");
//Matching all urls containing moz and chrome
var pattern = new MatchPattern(/.*moz.*/);
var pattern2 = new MatchPattern(/.*chrome.*/);

var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var data = require("self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: [pattern, pattern2],
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.7.1.min.js'),data.url('jquery-ui.js')]

});
```

But Error console is showing this error:

> Timestamp: 3/19/2012 9:03:34 PM Error: An exception occurred.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "resource://jid0-m6oqvn6bm6wcoo89bddsxwddkou-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/match-pattern.js",
>   line 87, in MatchPattern_test
>       this.regexp.exec(urlStr)[0] == urlStr) TypeError: this.regexp.exec is not a function

What am I doing wrong here? Can I pass regexp match patterns in `include` array of `pageMod`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing when I read the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use the `match-pattern` package directly, it is being used by the `page-mod` module internally. Just pass the regular expressions in the `include` parameter:

```js
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: [/.*moz.*/, /.*chrome.*/],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the ability to use regular regex objects / expressions is not as well advertised in the docs as it could be.

Comment: Well, it's there in the documentation if you look closely but an example using regexps/lists of expressions in `page-mod` would be nice.